# Такие разные Ильичи

Tags: орфография, ономастика, история

Многие знают, что в творительном падеже главного Ильича надо писать через Ё: с Владимиром Ильичём. А любых других Ильичей, даже дорогого Леонида Ильича – через О: с Леонидом Ильичом. Кто может объяснить почему?!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Правда ли, что отчество Ильич в творительном падеже пишется через Ё, если речь о Ленине, и через О в остальных случаях?

Ильичём – так до перестройки вопреки правилам писали отчество Владимира Ильича Ленина.
О написании Ильичём (о Ленине) вместо полагающегося по Правилам 1956 г. Ильичом интересно пишет Б. З. Букчина:

«Члены Орфографической комиcсии, готовившие Свод (имеется в виду Свод правил русской орфографии и пунктуации 1956 г. – Прим. Грамоты), обратили внимание на то, что форма Ильичём (Лениным), как правило, писалась через ё (в частности, такое написание встретилось в одном из писем Н. К. Крупской). Чтобы сохранить орфографическую неприкосновенность В. И. Ленина, было принято «устное» исключение: писать, например, Петром Ильичом (Чайковским).., но Владимиром Ильичём (Лениным). ... Правило это даже в годы застоя не распространилось шире – например, на «верного ленинца» Л. И. Брежнева. ..... даже по поводу родных братьев В. И. Ленина не было ясности: писать ли Дмитрием, Александром Ильичём или Ильичом!» (Б. З. Букчина. Об одном негласном орфографическом исключении // Язык: система и подсистема. М., 1990, с.75–76).

А по правилам надо писать (и так делается сегодня): Ильичом.

Правильно

Петром Ильичом Чайковским

Владимиром Ильичом Лениным

См.: Словарь трудностей. Словарь подготовлен профессором Ю. А. Бельчиковым и доцентом О. И. Ражевой. (Грамота.ру)

Comment: Серёж, а Серёж... Я разобралась, что тебя вывело на неверный путь: одно из значений глагола "давать". ***Давай(те), в зн. частицы. (с инф. нсв. или с 1 л. мн. ч. буд. вр.). Разг. 1. Выражает приглашение к совместному действию или побуждение к действию. Д. мириться! Давайте посидим, отдохнём, покурим. Спи д.! Давайте поторапливайтесь. Д. отсюда! (грубо; убирайся). Д. все по домам (расходись, разбегайся). Давай бог ноги (о быстром, поспешном бегстве).*** http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&ro=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=+%D0%94%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C

Comment: @Galina Avanesova, вы, случайно, не перепутали местами вопрос?

Comment: Нет, я опасалась, что у меня коммент к моему же комменту, и ты заблудишься. А тут - чистенькое местечко нашла. Можешь удалить. "Случайно" без запятых, "Вы" с прописной, и с чего это мы вдруг так повзрослели? О_о. Мы ж не кусаемся, а разговариваем.

Comment: Про "повзраслели" и "кусаемся" вообще ничего не понял. Случайно в данном случае - вводное слово.  Что касается местоимения Вы. С прописной буквы пишутся местоимения Вы, Ваш как форма выражения вежливости при обращении к одному конкретному лицу в письмах, официальных документах и т. п., напр.: Поздравляем Вас... Сообщаем Вам... В ответ на Ваш запрос... Так же пишутся слова Вы и Ваш в текстах, предназначенных для многократного использования, типа анкет, реклам, листовок. (Правила русской орфографии и пунктуации. Полный академический справочник / Под ред. В. В. Лопатина. М., 2013. § 202).

Comment: Удалить можете только вы.

Comment: Та хай живэ... Мне казалось, что мы были на "ты", к перемене и относится "повзросление". А зачем ты мне правила приводишь, зная, что я ими не пользуюсь? О_о Обижаешь старушку... "Вы" с прописной - при любом письменном обращение к одному лицу.

Comment: Галина, я всегда обращался к вам на вы. Не припомню, чтобы на ты обращался к вам. А сам я не против обращения ко мне на ты. Пожалуйста!

Comment: И я - пожалуйста! Ну мы тут все коллеги по несчастью, и я на "вы" только с теми, кого, чую, травмирует иное.